# Why did my client folder is not being pushed to github

Tags: github, mern

This is driving me crazy, i know this sounds like a dumb question but i have been struggling with this for like 2 days.
I just finished coding on my Visual Code , and i wanted to push it on github. So i created a new repository named mern-maps , below i show you guys my folder structure

[image]

this is how i tried to push my project to newly created repository
[image]
[image]

**BUT ,** when i checked on my github , my client folder is not showing anything, it even has the commit messages that i created 2 weeks ago.

[image]

What is wrong with my project ? how can i push all of them ? it is okay if i need to create a new repo or something . Thank you for your time!

Comment: Maybe you've added some restrictions in the .gitignore file?

Comment: from your commits: "Submodule client added at 0b3ab1". So client is a submodule. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=git+push+submodule

Answer (score 2):

So you need to delete the git folder from the client and then go out of the clien and create a new git folder starting with git init. In order to see the git if you are on vscode,go to your settings and write files.exclude, when you see the git just delete it as hidden option and you will see it in folder as default.Delete it from the client folder and as l told you go out of client and create the new git folder.

Answer (score 0):

Enable hidden folder option and delete .git folder inside client folder.
and again open the terminal from server root folder and type:

```
git init
```

[image]